# Populate a razor dropdownlist based on a value in the same row (model value)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

Am using the following syntax to populate a dropdown list in MVC, the dropdown binds the values correctly. But i want to fiter the 'SelectList' before bind it into dropdown.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Requests)
  <tr>                     {
      <td>
           @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AssignedTo)
      </td>
      <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartedOn)
      </td>
      <td>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RequestStatus, new SelectList(Model.RequestStatus, "StatusID", "StatusDescription"))
      </td>
  </tr>
```

I have a model RequestStatus is as follows,

```
 public class RequestStatusModel
 {
     public string RequestID { get; set; }
     public string StatusID { get; set; }
     public string StatusDescription { get; set; }
 }
```

View model '***RequestModel***' given below, the grid binds the Requests collection data. ie  IList Requests, which contains RequestID field.

```
public class RequestModel
{
     public IList<Request> Requests { get; set; }
     public IList<RequestStatusModel> RequestStatus { get; set; }
}
```

The sample data in RequestStatusModel.

```
  RequestID       StatusID          StatusDescription
  ====================================================     
      111           1000              Assigned
      111           1001              UnAssigned
      111           1002              In progress
      222           1003              Started
      222           1004              In progress
      222           1005              Stopped
      333           1006              Assigned
      333           1007              Completed
```

Sample data in Requests collection

```
RequestID   AssignedTo   StartedOn
  111         SAM        05/12/2012
  333         KEN        02/23/2006
  222         RAJ        11/30/2006
```

Now the dropdown list binds all the StatusDescription, but i want to bind the **Statusdescription** from RequestStatusModel based on *RequestID* in Request collection

Comment: One option is to have RequestViewModel with FilteredRequestStatus property which will filter the data based on your preference

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you need

```
public class RequestModel
{
    public IList<Request> Requests { get; set; }
    public IList<RequestStatusModel> RequestStatus { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<RequestStatusModel> FilteredRequestStatus
    {
        get
        {
            return RequestStatus.Where(rs => Requests.Select(r => r.RequestID).Contains(rs.RequestID));
        }
    }

}
```

and your view

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Requests)
  <tr>                     {
      <td>
           @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AssignedTo)
      </td>
      <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartedOn)
      </td>
      <td>
            @Html.DropDownList("RequestStatus", new SelectList(Model.FilteredRequestStatus, "StatusID", "StatusDescription"))
      </td>
  </tr>
```